# How to discard the controller/action values on URL when using YII framework?

Tags: php, yii, yii-url-manager

We can use URL Manager to change the URL parameters as different category, but how do i maintain the application URL should be www.xxxx.com whatever the process i am doing.

It should display the exact website name only and hide the all other parameters like controller/action/id...etc etc.

I searched for many sites but could not found the solutions.

Simply i need like this www.xxxxx.com instead of http://www.xxxxx.com/timesheet/manage_timesheet

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this rule inside your url-manager rules:

```
"timesheet/manage_timesheet" => ""
```

I didn't test it, but I think you can try it.

Comment: It is not working because you need to set controller and action. for example: "timesheet/manage_timesheet" => "site/index"

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this but it might work.

in your config file, set

```
'defaultController' => 'timesheet',
```

in TimesheetController, add

```
 public $defaultAction = 'manage_timesheet';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this setting, it should be work for you as your needs.

```
//first set default Controller
'defaultController' => 'timesheet'
```

configure in your **Url Manager**

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'showScriptName'=>false,
    'rules'=>array(
        'timesheet'=> 'timesheet/manage_timesheet'
    )
)
```

Or use `''=> 'timesheet/manage_timesheet'` instead of `'timesheet'=> 'timesheet/manage_timesheet'`